# generate json file from Postgres in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

I am trying when I run a ruby file to generate a json file, the script is working but it just display the json on the terminal, I don't know to to create a file from it, here is what I did :

```
  require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.connect("host", 5432, '', '', "d6kabu5l22jugs", "cgcscdqtkpesow", "5fe2bc97a")

res  = conn.exec('select * FROM applicants')
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(applicants)) FROM applicants;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is execute the query and then write it on to a file.

```
require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.connect("host", 5432, '', '', "d6kabu5l22jugs", "cgcscdqtkpesow", "5fe2bc97a")

res  = conn.exec("
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(a)) as response FROM (select * from applications) a")
```

once you got the result you write it to a file.

```
File.open("dump.json","w") do |f|
  f.write(res.first['response'])
end
```